# Selenium: 'package org.openqa.selenium does not exist'

Tags: java, selenium

[image: Terminal: Error message]

[image: Eclipse IDE: Program set-up]

Receiving two (2) error messages:

```
package org.openqa.selenium does not exist
package org.openqa.selenium.chrome does not exist
```

Here's what my program looks like: **MyClass.java**

```
package newPackage;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class MyClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",
                "/Users/Informatics/Downloads/chromedriver.exe");

        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("google.com");

        driver.close();
    }
}
```

p.s. I'm using the newest versions of Eclipse, Selenium, Chrome and Java.

Answer (score 1):

If ur using intellijIdea add this in dependencies in build.gradle file

```
implementation group: 'org.seleniumhq.selenium', name: 'selenium-java', version: '4.1.1'
```

I have added as testimplementation group so got error , it should be implementation group to add all jars

Answer (score 0):

In my case the error was that I had imported the project in IntelliJ as an Eclipse project instead of a Maven project.
Then it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using IntelliJ then after adding the dependency in the pom.xml,
Right click on the project
click "Maven"
click "Reload project".
This should resolve the issue.